# Riddle: 3 generations all have name that can be read backwards and forwards

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, riddle

Where in Tanach do you have 3 generations - father, son, grandson, - all have names that can be read backwards and forwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nasan david yishai

Answer (score 1):

Dovid Yishai and Asa